# How to configure cascade squid proxy with squid parent digest authentication

Tags: squid, digest-authentication

How can I configure a squid proxy behind another proxy that requires digest authentication?
I have this line in my squid conf, but the parent proxy keeps asking me username and password.

```
cache_peer $PARENTIP parent $PARENTPORT 0 default no-query proxy-only login=$user:$pass
```

It doesn't have to be a squid if there is another solution.

Answer (score 3):

For those who come upon this question on search, forwarding requests to a parent proxy works using basic proxy authentication (without failover) via the following configuration.  This allows squid to manage the forwarding and authentication to the parent proxy without the additional client credential configuration.

```
cache_peer $PARENT_PROXY_HOST parent $PARENT_PROXY_PORT 0 default no-query login=$PARENT_PROXY_USERNAME:$PARENT_PROXY_PASSWORD
never_direct allow localhost
```

However, I couldn't get this to work with proxy digest authentication.  This, apparently, isn't supported by squid via a cache_peer configuration declaration [[squid mailing list citation]](http://lists.squid-cache.org/pipermail/squid-users/2015-June/004122.html).

One can manage this by storing or passing the configuration credentials (username/password) at the client and then passing them through to the squid proxy.  This works for basic and digest authentication.   The client passes the credentials.   squid, in this case, does not require authentication, but passes through the client-provided credentials to the parent proxy which does require them.

```
cache_peer $PARENT_PROXY_HOST parent $PARENT_PROXY_PORT 0 default no-query login=PASSTHRU
never_direct allow localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
never_direct:


acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
cache_peer $PARENTID parent 8080 0 default no-query proxy-only login=a:b
never_direct allow localhost
http_port 8080
```

Comment: that work with the digest authentication in the parent proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you install redsocks on the same machine where child squid is running you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a supplement to the first answer, and in case it will be useful to the latecomer.

If your Squid cannot access https but can access http. The following information may be useful to you.
Without considering security, consider adding the following values to make https accessible.

```
never_direct allow all
```

Comment out the following values

```
#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```